# How to make my popup not transparent and sideways draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a Jquery popup / dialog and I've manged to position it on the page at a click so that the div renders over the other elements but the page is transparent and when I drag it, I can drag it upwards and downwards but when I drag it sideways it resizes instead of moves. can you tell me what I could do to resolve these 2 issues?

It looks like this

[image]

My popup HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>popup</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" class="TB_nb">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök person/företag</h2> 
</td>
  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display = 'none';" >X</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<h2 class="pusher">Sök person/företag</h2>
<div id="Vsok">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='none'" class="link_sm">Visa s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

</div>

<div id="sokF">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display=''" class="link_sm">D&ouml;lj s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 80px;" class="fontS80">
<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Fysisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchFornamn" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Efternamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchEfternamn" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Juridisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;retag:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchForetag" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Organisationsnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchOrgNummer" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
</fieldset> <br><br>

<!-- <div class="fl30">Attention, c/o etc.:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Postadress:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Postnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="30"></div>
<div class="clear"></div> -->

<div class="fl30">Postort:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40" name="searchPostort" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Land:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="2" name="searchLandKod" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')">&nbsp;
                    <select name="searchLand" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">---------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<!-- <div class="fl30">Region:</div>
<div class="fl20"><select name="">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">-----------------------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">Tel:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Fax:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">E-post:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
 -->
<div class="fl50">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="fl5"><input type="button" value="Rensa"></div>
<div class="fl10"><input type="button" value="  S&ouml;k  " onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</div>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center">
<tr>    
    <td><h3>Sökresultat:</h3></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td colspan="4">En massa text <span class="link">Hj&auml;lp!</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td><input type="button" value="Visa alla"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="smallb">
    <td>Antal &auml;renden: 527</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Visa &auml;renden: &#60;&#60; 1-200 201-400 401-527 &#62;&#62; </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="sortable" id="unique_id">
<tr>
    <th class="thkant">F&ouml;rnamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Efternamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Adress</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postnr</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postort</th>
    <th class="thkant">Region</th>
    <th class="thkant">Land</th>
    <th class="thkant">Telefonnummer</th>
</tr>


</table>


<div id="bottomV">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" id="visaknapp" value="Visa" disabled style="width:150px;" onClick="getElementById('sokR').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='none', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='', getElementById('sokF').style.display='none'"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" disabled style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="bottomA" style="display: none">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" value="&Auml;ndra i register" style="width:150px;"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is

```
.newpopup {
  position: absolute; 
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

The Javascript is

```
function popup() {
    alert('test');
    var popup = $('.newpopup');
    popup.draggable();
    popup.resizable();
    //popup.html('<p>Where is pancakes house?</p>');
    //popup.show('fast');

       $.get('/PandoraArendeWeb/popup.jsp', function(data) {   

        popup.html(data); 
        popup.show('fast'); 
    }); 

    var screen_width = $(document).width();
var screen_height = $(document).height();
var box_width = popup.width();
var box_height = popup.height();

var top = (screen_height - box_height) / 2; // you might like to subtract a little to position it slightly higher than half way
var left = (screen_width - box_width) / 2;
    popup.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':top, 'left':left });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     popup();
  });
})
```

Please tell me how to

1) make the popup not transparent
2) make the popup sideways draggable

The HTML that actually activates the popup is trivial:

```
<div class='newpopup'>
</div>
<button>popup</button>
```

Thank you

Comment: please strip your html and css to only the problem at hand, also consider a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: to make it not transparent just set a background color in your .newpopup CSS class

Comment: Also where is the html for the popup as .newpopup does not exist in your html

Comment: pick the suitable background color from this site http://html-color-codes.info and set it in .newpopup class of css: background-color: the color you choose;

Comment: If you're using JQuery UI (I assume you are since you've got resizable and draggable), why not just use the JQuery UI dialog too? http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: @Karl Nicoll Thanks for the link. I'm trying the Jqueri UI dialog now but I can't seem to understand how to load html into it from an url. I suppose there should be a way. I also want to not have the page "roll up" when I activate the dialog, I'd like the page to stay scrolled down if the button is pressed to activate a popup / dialog when the page is scrolled down. Could you please tell me something about how I can achieve what I'm looking for? thank you

Comment: @Rutwik Reddy thank you for the link. But for some reason the popup is still transparent when I've added `background-color: #FFFFFF;` What can be the matter?

Comment: @AbstractChaos thanks for the comment. I added the missing HTML to the question.

Comment: @epoch I followed what you said, added `background-color: #FFFFFF;` to the newpopup of my CSS but the popup is still transparent which is strange. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any more ideas? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: Guys, it's not working and still the same problem as in the original question. It's like the CSS is not there and the DIV gets transparent and impossible to drag sideways. I'm sorry that JQuery is not working and I'm wondering if you have any idea what to do about this? I can't post a jsfiddle with the code since the DIV loads a page from an internal server and it is that page that doesn't render properly.

Comment: Maybe it is not transparent and just rendering below the other page components? If so, what could be done to resolve it?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz `z-index` is the one which controls whats on top of what but without the full css it would be hard to determine that, hence no1 has that solution :)

Comment: @AbstractChaos You're right, it is the CSS. I had to leave this problem for a while to get a more basic version of the page functional, now I can go on and make the popups with JQuery now that they all work like regular DIVs and actually render over the other elements. I'll look more into this in the next few days. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I created  simple test case using jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RZWPR/2/), i dont think theres anything wrong with your jquery but i believe it the ajax call so to test this as on your server to make sure your ajax call is working (as i cant), if your ajax call falls it will not popup. in the test case it will alert "Error".

HTML:

```
<button>popup</button>
<div class='newpopup'>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function popup() {
    alert('opening popup');
    var popup = $('.newpopup');
    popup.draggable();
    popup.resizable();
    //popup.html('<p>Where is pancakes house?</p>');
    //popup.show('fast');

    //Comment me out and use the version below to show working
    $.ajax({url:'/PandoraArendeWeb/popup.jsp',
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            },
            success: function(data) {   
                popup.html("test"); 
                popup.show('fast');
            }
       }
   ); 
   
    
   /*
    popup.html("test"); 
    popup.show('fast');
    */
    var screen_width = $(document).width();
var screen_height = $(document).height();
var box_width = popup.width();
var box_height = popup.height();

var top = (screen_height - box_height) / 2; // you might like to subtract a little to position it slightly higher than half way
var left = (screen_width - box_width) / 2;
    popup.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':top, 'left':left });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     popup();
  });
})​
```

​
CSS:

```
.newpopup {
  position: absolute; 
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:#ff0; //Yellow
} ​
```

**EDIT**
Just remembered try commenting out the ajax and use the bit below. the popup shows and you can drag it :)

Comment: The code you posted works but it doesn't solve the problem. I still can't load the page from an url using `.get` with my javascript and the DIV does not become sideways draggable. This is very strange indeed that JQuery is not working. Thanks anyway for the answer and please post again if you got any more ideas how to make JQuery work the way it should.

Comment: did you try commenting out the ajax code like i said... it showed the popup and was draggable

Comment: Also in your html there is no <script></script> tags to import jquery is that missing or did you just omit them?

Comment: What is the full url of `/PandoraArendeWeb/popup.jsp`?